# NTP update causing C# Winforms Timer to pause

Tags: c#, winforms, raspberry-pi, mono, ntp

I'm running C# mono (linux) on raspberry pi .NET 4.5.

For the purpose of this simple test program, let's say I've got a simple form with a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

If I let the program run at start-up (before NTP updates the time), the timer runs fine until NTP decides to update the system time. The system time before NTP is a couple of minutes fast; when NTP updates the time, the timer `Tick` function stops getting called.

After waiting several minutes (about the same time as the clock was fast to begin with) , the timer `Tick` function continues again as normal.

NTP (network time protocol)

```
Jul 18 16:02:44 hostname systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
Jul 18 16:03:32 hostname systemd-timesyncd[366]: Synchronized to time server for the first time 193.150.34.2:123 (2.debian.pool.ntp.org).
```

In the above log, the C# program started about the same time as the "*Started Network Time Synchronization*" and run fine for just under a minute until 16:03:32 when the timer paused.

Designer:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer LogTimer;
```

Form1.cs

```
public void Form1_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Logging interval
    LogTimer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.LogTimer_tick);
    LogTimer.Interval = 100;
    LogTimer.Start();
}

private void LogTimer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // do stuff (display time)
   lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss");
}
```

The question is - how can I detect a system time change (with C# mono on linux) so that I can manually reset the timer Tick continues as normal (such that it doesn't pause) ?

Comment: `System.Threading.Timer` is not dependent on the system clock.

Comment: Try `System.Timers.Timer` in that context, it should work better

Comment: BTW, avoid `// do stuff` stuff in the handler of any timer. If you just need to update a Control, then just `BeginInvoke(new Action(()=> lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(...)));` (or set the SynchronizingObject to the Form instance)

Comment: You only hope is to migrate to .NET Core and another UI framework. Mono isn't a true option https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/ and https://halfblood.pro/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea

Comment: Thanks for the comments . I tried System.Timers.Timer with SyncronisingObject which compiled fine as I've got a lot of UI stuff but it still suffered from the NTP "bug". I will attempt System.Thread.Timer next but that will be a lot more work to change all the code to Invokes (Which probably should have been done like that anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks from the comments - I have tried the following with System.Timers.Timer as suggested and appears to be working so far.

Form1.cs

```
private System.Timers.Timer LogTimer;

public void Form1_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Logging interval
    LogTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    LogTimer.Elapsed += LogTimer_Elapsed;
    LogTimer.SynchronizingObject = this;
    LogTimer.Interval = 100;
    LogTimer.Start();
}

private void LogTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   // do stuff (display time)
   lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss");
}
```

Also an [update to mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/20596) is required.